# C++ SFML Collision detection sometimes fails

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sfml, pong

I am making a Pong game using c++ with SFML. Most of the time, the collision detection works well; however, sometimes it fails outright, giving no error message. It does this seemingly unpredictably, so it is not just one circumstance that causes it, which is why I do not know what the problem is. Here is the code for the collision detection:

```
bool circleRectCollisionDetection(int CircleX,int CircleY,int CircleRadius,int RectX,int RectY,int RectWidth,int RectHeight){
  int DeltaX = CircleX - max(RectX, min(CircleX, RectX + RectWidth));
  int DeltaY = CircleY - max(RectY, min(CircleY, RectY + RectHeight));
  return (DeltaX * DeltaX + DeltaY * DeltaY) < (CircleRadius * CircleRadius);
}
```

And here is where it is called:

```
  int ballx = ball->getX();
  int bally = ball->getY();
  int rotation = ball->getRotation();
  int player1x = player1->getX();
  int player2x = player2->getX();
  int player1y = player1->getY();
  int player2y = player2->getY();


  //left Paddle
  if(circleRectCollisionDetection(ballx,bally,30,player1x,player1y,30,150)){
    cout<<"1"<<endl;
    ball->setX(player1x+80);
    ball->invertXFunc();

  }

  //right paddle
  if(circleRectCollisionDetection(ballx,bally,30,player2x,player2y,30,150)){
    cout<<"2"<<endl;

    ball->setX(player2x-80);
    ball->invertXFunc();
  }
```

Comment: What does the failure look like? The detection glitches? Run-time error?

Comment: What happens if in the delta-time interval objectA passes all the way through objectB?  This is a known problem with this sort of collision test.

Comment: The particular glitch Robert is referring to also tends to happen in collisions between high-speed objects--another shortcoming of that type of collision test.

Comment: How could I fix it?

Comment: Easiest fix is too shorten the delta.

Comment: How would I shorten the delta time? Isn't dependent on the speed of the computer?

Comment: Don't know which framework you're using. Have you currently bound it to the framerate? You shouldn't do that. You're better off decoupling physics delta time and framerate. See here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/104007/how-do-i-separate-physics-from-framerate